# Indentation problems

Tags: python, indentation

I can't quite get this python program to work, each time i run it, it comes up with the 'inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation' error on line 25 which is the 'else' loop. I've tried various methods of fixing this all to no avail, and so was wondering if anyone could explain my problem. Thank you very much for the time.

```
questions = ["What does RAD stand for?",
        "Why is RAD faster than other development methods?",
        "Name one of the 3 requirements for a user friendly system",
        "What is an efficient design?",
        "What is the definition of a validation method?"]


answers = ["A - Random Applications Development, B - Recently Available Diskspace, C - Rapid Applications Development",
        "A - Prototyping is faster than creating a finished product, B - Through the use of CASE tools, C - As end user evaluates before the dev team",
        "A - Efficient design, B - Intonated design, C - Aesthetic design",
        "A - One which makes best use of available facilities, B - One which allows the user to input data accurately, C - One which the end user is comfortable with",
        "A - A rejection of data which occurs because input breaks predetermined criteria, B - A double entry of data to ensure it is accurate, C - An adaption to cope with a change external to the system"]

correctanswers = ["C", "B", "A", "A", "A"]

score = 0

for i in range(len(questions)):
    a = 1
    print (questions[a])
    print (answers[a])
    useranswer = (input("Please enter the correct answer's letter here:"))
    correctanswer = correctanswers[a]
    if useranswer is correctanswer:
            print("Correct, well done!")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect, sorry!")

print("Well done, you scored" + score + "//" + int(len(questions)))
```

Comment: `'else' loop`?? -> else if not a loop.

Comment: After the `if` statement, till the `print` of `else`, move every statement 4 spaces to the left. I think that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing tabs and spaces, run python with `-tt` to check:

```
python -tt scriptname.py
```

Configure your editor to *only* use spaces for indentation. Usually, there is a menu option to convert all tabs to spaces as well.

Clearly, when you pasted the code into the Stack Overflow window, you can already see that your `else:` line is using only spaces, but the other lines are using tabs:

```
    if useranswer is correctanswer:
            print("Correct, well done!")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect, sorry!")
```

because Stack Overflow renders tabs to 4 spaces.

Comment: `if` and `else` must have the same identation = the same number of whitespaces before them

Answer (score 1):

When indenting code, *either* use tabs *or* spaces. Do not mix those (i.e. you can't use tabs on one line and spaces on the next).

Comment: And any good python editor has a checkbox in settings "Convert tabs to spaces" if one must use the tab-button

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` should be at the same indentation level of the `if`.

```
   if useranswer is correctanswer:
        print("Correct, well done!")
        score = score + 1
   else:
        print("Incorrect, sorry!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Atleast on this codeblock, your if and else are on different intendations, and they should be at the same.

```
if useranswer is correctanswer:
        print("Correct, well done!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect, sorry!")
```

should be:

```
if useranswer is correctanswer:
        print("Correct, well done!")
        score = score + 1
else:
        print("Incorrect, sorry!")
```